# Workflow to trigger email to contact

Tags: workflow

**Business Processes**

Email to Contact

**Object**: TestAppCon

**Description**

Send an email to contact when appId field and conId field on TestAppCon are populated

**Evaluate the rule when a record is:**

created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

**Rule Criteria (Filter)**

what could be the rule criteria for this???

Tried this :- IF( ISNULL( Application_*c ) &&  ISNULL( Contact*_c ) , FALSE, TRUE) 
Its not working

Comment: can you please tell what is the data type of those two fields?

Comment: This fields are lookup to application and contact.

Comment: try this :  NOT( AND( ISBLANK(Application_c), ISBLANK(Contact_c) ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISBLANK instead of ISNULL.

"Use ISBLANK instead of ISNULL in new formulas. ISBLANK has the same functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. Salesforce will continue to support ISNULL, so you do not need to change any existing formulas."

Source:
http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISBLANK